# How i can use jquery for insert data in table without submit a form

Tags: jquery

I am developping an accounting software. i need to use jquery submission code for insert data into table without submission form? can you please help me?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be writing a service, depending on your backend language with that language.  Please provide that information for more information on that specific language.  With your service written you will call the service using `.ajax` or `.post` (`.post` is just a variant of `.ajax`) this you can call anytime, on page ready, on button click, on link click, on timer, whenever...

That's about it, you'll know success or failure and thereby whether the service failed or succeeded.

Special Note:

If this is a external facing site and service please be aware that without using a security measure like OAuth anyone can call this service and do whatever it is doing.